# Como truncar calculo a 2 decimales sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Hola a todos espero puedan ayudarme, intento realizar un calculo en sql server, aunque el calculo lo realiza me manda 13 decimales y por mas que he intentado poner solo 2 decimales no he podido.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
select
(CAST(22704 AS float)-ROUND(CAST(Total_Hombres+Total_Mujeres AS float),2,1))/ROUND(CAST(22704 AS float),2,1)*100 as poblacionmenosestimada
from mitabla
```

Comment: Solo engloba tu resultado a un round 
SELECT  round(
(CAST(22704 AS float)-ROUND(CAST(Total_Hombres+Total_Mujeres AS float),2,1))/ROUND(CAST(22704 AS float),2,1)*100,2, 1) as poblacionmenosestimada 
FROM mitabla

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que cambiar de lugar la función `ROUND()` para que englobe toda la operación. Dejo ejemplo con datos de prueba.

```
WITH mitabla AS(
    SELECT  26785 AS Total_Hombres,
            56133 AS Total_Mujeres
)
SELECT  ROUND((CAST(22704 AS float)-CAST(Total_Hombres+Total_Mujeres AS float)) / CAST(22704 AS float) *100 ,2,1) as TodaLaOperacion,
        ROUND((CAST(22704 AS float)-CAST(Total_Hombres+Total_Mujeres AS float)) / CAST(22704 AS float),2,1) *100  as SoloLaDivision,
        ROUND((CAST(22704 AS float)-CAST(Total_Hombres+Total_Mujeres AS float)),2,1) / CAST(22704 AS float) *100  as SoloLaResta 
FROM  mitabla;
```